# Can't figure out how to pass arguments to a bind function

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

After several tries of trying to pass arguments in a scroll event function, It's not working.

I'm making a custom scroll panel and need the bind function to trigger when the user scrolls down, in order to do that I need to pass variables that are going to be used inside the panel. This wasn't an issue with the wxScrolledWindow since I didn't have to bind anything and could just make a function for it and call it directly.

Some of these arguments  I don't necessarily need to pass in as I can get them by using `event.GetEventObject();` but the rest like `m`  which is a map I need to pass on.

Among the solutions I've tried shown below, I thought of making a hidden panel with the map already inside or near the "scroll panel" so I can access it using the `event.GetEventObject();` but I'm leaving it as a last-ditch effort (if that would even work). I'm really hoping there's an easier way. Any help is appreciated.

Attempt #1

```
ScrolledWindow->Bind(wxEVT_SCROLLWIN_PAGEDOWN, &MyFrame::ScrolledWindowCreate, this)(m, ScrolledWindow, ScrolledWindowMain, ScrolledWindowSizer, initalWindowWidth));
```

Attempt #2

```
// Saw a thread that said parameters should be put outside

ScrolledWindow->Bind(wxEVT_SCROLLWIN_PAGEDOWN, &MyFrame::ScrolledWindowCreate, this)(m, ScrolledWindowContainerSub, ScrolledWindowMain, ScrolledWindowSizer, initalWindowWidth);
```

Attempt #3

```
// Tried to pass the arguments as the userData as in the WxWidgets documentation, the WxWidgets forums suggested it, but I looked and apparently, I need to pass in a wxObject? I don't know how a set of arguments is supposed to be turned into a wxObject 

ScrolledWindow->Bind(wxEVT_SCROLLWIN_PAGEDOWN, &MyFrame::ScrolledWindowCreate, this, -1, (m, ScrolledWindowContainerSub, ScrolledWindowMain, ScrolledWindowSizer, initalWindowWidth);
```

Update:

So I found out that you need to store the arguments as wxClientData, I believe I've done so successfully but I still don't know how to extract the individual items from it.

```
struct CustomData final : public wxClientData {

    int PanelNum = 20;
    std::list<std::string> TagList{ "Paid", "Needs invoice" };
    std::map<std::string, std::variant<std::string, std::list<std::string>>> m{ {"TIME","8:69"}, {"HEADER","Title"},{"TAGS", TagList},{"CONTENT", "Hey this is content!"} };
    wxPanel* ScrolledWindowContainerSub;
    wxPanel* ScrolledWindowMain;
    wxBoxSizer* ScrolledWindowSizer;
    int initalWindowWidth = 1300;
};


 // Panels that are set as arguments below are defined here 
// wxPanel* ScrolledWindowContainerSub = ...; etc...

CustomData* const myData{ new CustomData() };
    myData->PanelNum, m, ScrolledWindowContainerSub, ScrolledWindowMain, ScrolledWindowSizer, initalWindowWidth;
    ScrolledWindowContainerSub->SetClientObject(myData);
    ScrolledWindowContainerSub->Bind(wxEVT_SCROLL_BOTTOM, &MyFrame::ScrolledWindowScrolled, this);


void MyFrame::ScrolledWindowScrolled(wxScrollEvent& event) {

wxObject* Obj = event.GetEventObject();
wxClientData* ObjClientData = static_cast<wxEvtHandler*>(Obj)->GetClientObject();


wxPanel* ObjStaticChild = dynamic_cast<wxPanel*>(ObjClientData); // Which panel will this give me? I've put two as parameters
```

};

Comment: The first version has 2 `(` and 3 `)` and the third version has 2 `(` and 1 `)`. Can you please fix the syntax errors?

Comment: @mch I'm aware of the syntax errors. These are attempts not versions

Comment: Please ask a separate question for your follow up question. This makes the already existing answer obsolete.

Comment: @Pal, why not just make those variables to be members of the scrolled panel?

Comment: @igor how do I do that?

Comment: @Pal, just make them members of MyFrame class...

Comment: @igor lol I'm embarrassed to say that'll probably work for what I'm doing. Didn't even cross my mind. I might have to find workarounds since I'll need to import these from a database in the future but It should work. Thanks a bunch

Comment: @Pal, and its actually corresponds to what Vadim is telling you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Bind()` does support passing pointers to arbitrary "user data", but this is not the best way to do it and is only supported for backwards compatibility and to ease migration of the very old code predating `Bind()`.

Instead, consider making the data you need part of some object -- typically something deriving from a window class and representing the window you're binding to, but not necessarily so -- and bind to a member function of this object, in which you will have access to all the data you need.

Remember that you don't need to bind to the object generating the event, or its parent. You can use anything you want, including a lambda, for example.

Comment: Is it normal for the app to crash if you put the variables into the MyFrame class under private? I don't get any syntax errors, the scroll event seems to be picked up and the ScrolledWindowScrolled function seems to pick up on the member variables. Don't know what to do

Comment: No, it is never normal for the app to crash, but this can't be related to making a member private. Check that you pass the pointer to the correct object when binding to a member, i.e. if you `Bind(..., &Foo::OnSomething, p)`, your `p` must actually point to a `Foo` and not something else.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax that you're using in `Bind` for binding the event to the event handler is incorrect.

From [event handler's documentation](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/overview_events.html) the correct syntax would be something like:

```
//-------------------------------------------------------------------vv--->no need of other things here
Bind(wxEVT_SCROLLWIN_PAGEDOWN, &MyFrame::ScrolledWindowCreate, this);
```

Comment: yes I know but i'm trying to pass in extra arguments

Comment: @Pal Refer to [bind's documentation](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_evt_handler.html) where they have mentioned its parameters. We are only allowed to pass arguments corresponding to those parameters. Trial and error( like you did in your example) won't work. Even the syntax in your given examples is invalid.